# An object cannot have key attribute

Tags: typescript

I need an object type that cannot have the attribute key.But other attributes can be owned.

```
const obj: ??? = {key:1, value: 1} // error:Cannot have the attribute key
```

```
const obj: ??? = {other1:1,other2:2} // OK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
type CanNotHaveKey = { [key: string]: any } & {
    key?: never
}

const obj: CanNotHaveKey = { key: 1, value: 1 } // ❌ Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
const objTwo: CanNotHaveKey = { other1: 1, nice: { good: "string" }, other2: 2 } // ✔
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgOwHIHtgAk4DcIGkIhQC8UA3lANoDWBAXFAM7ABOAlggOYC69ihAvlABkZAFBQJUGiAD89BBBzNR-UaIDGKBEygoARgCt68ZGkw58hEuWn0AjABooWOABsArhHtRBAel9QgDLkUAAq4NAA5AjuALZ6EMwRUKwMUAhoUHAMDKwcCHB6rtDAKFCgkFAR7ggAJhAAZuwQNREAdBpaOvoGIQDuKMaIqBjYeATEZLrAABYJdvZOCKzqXpMcKCg19ABETGyc2z5OaLPMAEz0Zz5Q-lCAKORQokA)

My idea behind it is to combine the types `any` and `key`, where `key` is a type which never occurs.

Read more about never: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never